# Error trying to screen an internal table abap

Tags: abap

I´m learning ABAP and I keep trying to write that internal table and show it. There's syntax error message at line `WRITE: / I_EJSEIS`:

> "I_EJSEIS" cannot be converted to a character-like value

I just don't understand it.

```
TYPES: S_EJSEIS LIKE SPFLI.
DATA: I_EJSEIS  TYPE TABLE OF S_EJSEIS WITH HEADER LINE,
      WA_EJSEIS TYPE S_EJSEIS.


SELECT FLTYPE
  FROM SPFLI
  INTO TABLE I_EJSEIS
  WHERE CARRID = 'LH'.

LOOP AT I_EJSEIS.
  WRITE: / I_EJSEIS.
ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the ABAP documentation of [`WRITE dobj`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapwrite-.htm):

> For dobj, those data types are allowed that are grouped under the generic type simple:
>
> - All flat data types; flat structures are handled like a data object of type c and can only contain any character-like components.
> - The data types string and xstring
> - enumerated types; the name (maximum three characters) of the enumerated constant is used in uppercase letters, which defines the current enumerated value.

In your case, `I_EJSEIS` is a (flat) structure containing at least one **non-character** component (e.g. `fltime`, `distance`, `period`), so it doesn't fall in any of the categories above.

The workaround is to display the fields individually:

```
WRITE: / I_EJSEIS-FLTYPE, I_EJSEIS-FLTIME.
```